# Alteryx and Formula

Tags: workflow, formula, alteryx

I have a series of numers that start with either 8 or 9, I would idealy like to categories these so for exable if starts with 8 change desctription to A if starts with 9 change description to B

Hopefully this makes sense, thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The believe following expression should work...

```
IIF(StartsWith(ToString([field]),'8')),'A','B')
```

IIF is an abbreviated IF... the longer form works just as well:

```
IF (StartsWith(ToSting([field]),'8')) THEN
    'A'
ELSE
    'B'
ENDIF
```

Also, the switch statement could be utilized also ...

```
Switch(Left(ToString([field]),1),
    '?',
    '8','A',
    '9','B')
```

There are probably other approaches too.